# Old App Bundle Still Active on Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

We tried to release the app on production but they are rejecting it due to an issue with the previous version of the uploaded application on the testing track.

Please guide us how to de-active that older app bundle or release the application on production.

[ScreenShot of mail received from google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQIbI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Open Testing version completely

Comment: Can you please tell us from where we can remove it.