# Play Console - App Bundle Explorer "Active" release status meaning

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

We have a policy problem with our application where they tell us we still have a permission that we superseded long ago in all tracks.

Checking the App Bundle Explorer I noted that those two old versions still show as "Active" under "Release status" column.

[image]
To my understanding the only way to "discard" a release is to supersede it with a new one on that same track, and we did that for example on the closed testing track for release 410:
[image]

I also checked this other question that wasn't helpful:
[Old App Bundle Still Active on Play Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73245252/old-app-bundle-still-active-on-play-console)

What is the meaning of that "Active" info in the App Bundle Explorer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth with Google and a lot of angry users we got replied by Google customer service was that a way to deactivate a version that still displays as "Active" was go on the related track on which that release is present and overwrite it with an "Empty" release. This is what they told me:

```
Thanks for your patience.

In this case, please create a new release(Empty) at the testing track, and make sure that the version you would like to deactivate is at the section of "Not Included."

And please note that the release: 410 (4.1.0) and 401 (4.0.1) still show as Active for the reason it's not been overridden.

If you have any other questions about using the Play Console, please let me know and I’ll be happy to help.
Regards,

Google Play Developer Support
```

Honestly this got us puzzled for a couple of weeks, and it seems a much better job could be done by Google in terms of explaining this matter.
This sounds more like an hack.